# Why is winbgi function settextstyle() occupying memory on the heap?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, bgi, winbgi

I am making a snake game in C using `winbgi` library. I have a problem with function `settextstyle()`. Every call of function adds memory to the heap (about 50kb). I have to use this function in loop, so at some point the heap starts to overflow. Is there a way to release memory occupied by this function? Or some other way to change the size of the text in `winbgi`?

```
while(1)
{
    settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 4)
    outtext(...)
    settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT, HORIZ_DIR, 2)
    outtext(...)
}
```

Comment: Please post a compilable [MCVE] for others to test, you will get help much more faster that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull the latest winbgi sources from [here](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/bgi/).

There was a bug (missing call to `DeleteObject()` after `SelectObject()` to set a new font in `set_font()`) within `text.cxx` which the code linked fixes.